# connected components of a real hyperplane arrangement

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let us consider the following configuration of hyperplanes in the real
vector space V with coordinates $z_1,\ldots,z_n$: the hyperplanes are
numbered by all the nonempty subsets $J\subset I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and the
hyperplane $H_J$ is given by $\sum_{i\in J}z_i=0$.

Question: How many connected components does the complement
$V\setminus\cup_{J}H_J$ have? That is, what are they naturally numbered by?

Comment: This is a trivial observation, but if you use the finite field method, you get the characteristic polynomial is $\chi(q) = q^n - |\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n) \in \mathbb{F}_q^n\colon \textrm{some nonempty subset of the $a_i$ sums to $0 \mod q$}\}|$. That looks like a terribly difficult counting problem, of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not known as far as I know, and seems to be a hard problem, see the references and comments in 
[this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62764/a-natural-refinement-of-the-a-n-arrangement-is-to-consider-all-2n-1-hyperpla).

Answer (score 3):

There is a formula for the number of components which unfortunately is pretty useless,
namely, 
  $$ \sum_{k,r} \frac{(-1)^{n+k+r}}{k!}f(k,n,r), $$
where $f(k,n,r)$ is the number of real $k\times n$ $(0,1)$-matrices of rank $r$ with no zero row and no two rows equal.