# probability of zero subset sum

Tags: additive-combinatorics, co.combinatorics, nt.number-theory

Almost 17 years ago, I asked the following question on USENET, motivated by a method in numerology (I kid you not).

Pick integers $n \ge 2$, $k \ge 1$. Toss $n$ $k$-sided dice.  The sides of each die are numbered $0,1,\ldots,k-1$.  The dice are unbiased and the tosses are independent.

**What is the probability $P(n,k)$ that no non-empty subset of the dice adds to a multiple of $k$?**

One can get answers with inclusion-exclusion, but it becomes rapidly more difficult as $n$ increases.  Simple cases are
$$k P(1,k) = k-1,$$
$$k^2 P(2,k) = (k-1)(k-2).$$
David desJardins found that
$$ k^3 P(3,k) = k^3 - 7 k^2 + 15 k - 9 - d_2(k), $$
$$ k^4 P(4,k) = k^4 - 15 k^3 + 80 k^2 - 170 k + 104 - (10 k - 40) d_2(k) + 10 d_3(k),$$
where
$$ d_2(k) = 1 \text{ if $k$ is even, 0 otherwise},$$ 
$$ d_3(k) = 1 \text{ if $k$ is 0 mod 3, otherwise}.$$
David also found the leading terms as $k\to\infty$ for fixed $n$, starting with
$$ P(n,k) = 1 - (2^n - 1)/k
         + 1/2 (4^n - 3^n - 2^n + 1)/k^2 + \cdots .$$

However, nobody found an exact formula, recursion, or generating function, or in fact any method for rapid computation when $n$ is large.  **That's my question.**

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I do know that this problem is related to (in fact, essentially equivalent to): http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118960/connected-components-of-a-real-hyperplane-arrangement and http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62764/a-natural-refinement-of-the-a-n-arrangement-is-to-consider-all-2n-1-hyperpla via the finite field method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, let me prove that all $P(n,k)=0$ for $n\geq k$, which follows from a simple lemma:

**Lemma.** In any sequence of $k\geq 1$ integers $m_1, m_2, \dots, m_k$, there exists a subsequence summing to a multiple of $k$.

**Proof.** Define $s_i := (m_1+m_2+\dots+m_i)\bmod k$, including $s_0=0$. By the pigeonhole principle, among the integers $s_0, s_1, s_2, \dots, s_k\in\{0, 1,\dots,k-1\}$, there exist two equal ones, say, $s_i=s_j$ for some $i<j$. Then $m_{i+1}, m_{i+2}, \dots, m_j$ form a required subsequence. QED

---

Now, let me discuss computing $P(n,k)$ for fixed $k$.

For any positive integer $n$ and any $S\subset \mathbb{Z}_k$, let $Q(n,S)$ denote the number of $n$-tuples from $\mathbb{Z}_k^n$ such that sum of any nonempty subsequence is not in $S$.

Then
$$Q(n,S) = \sum_{t\in \mathbb{Z}_k\setminus S} Q(n-1,S\cup (S-t)),$$
where $S-j := \{ s-t\mid s\in S\}$.
Furthermore, by definition we have $$Q(0,S) = 1.$$

In other words, if we fix and arbitrary indexing of the subsets of $\mathbb{Z}_k$, and let $\bar{Q}(n) := [Q(n,S_1),Q(n,S_2),\dots,Q(n,S_{2^k})]^T$, then
$$\bar{Q}(n) = M\cdot \bar{Q}(n-1) = M^n\cdot \bar{Q}(0),$$
where $M$ is a $2^k\times 2^k$ matrix with $M_{ij}$ equal the number of $t\in \mathbb{Z}_k\setminus S_i$ such that $S_j = S_i \cup (S_i - t)$. Clearly, $\bar{Q}(0)=[1,1,\dots,1]^T$.

It follows that for any $S$, the sequence $(Q(n,S))_{n\geq 0}$ satisfies an order $2^k$ linear recurrence, and in particular so does $k^n P(n,k) = Q(n,\{0\})$. This, however, is not so exciting as we know that the sequence $(k^n P(n,k))_{n\geq 0}$ stabilizes to $0$ starting with $n=k$. Still, the aforementioned formulae allow to compute $P(n,k)$ routinely, at least for small $k$.

---

**Example for $k=2$.** Let us fix the indexing: $S_1 = \emptyset$, $S_2=\{0\}$, $S_3=\{1\}$, and $S_4=\{0,1\}$. Then
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
with the minimal polynomial $x^4 - 3x^3 + 2x^2$. Hence, for $n\geq 4$
$$Q(n,S) = 3Q(n-1,S) - 2Q(n-2,S).$$
In particular, $(2^n P(n,2))_{n\geq 0} = (1,1,0,0,0,\dots)$, i.e., $P(n,2)=0$ for $n\geq 2$ as we already know.

**Examples for $k\leq 10$.** 
\begin{split}
(2^n P(n,2))_{n\geq 0} &= (1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \dots), \\
(3^n P(n,3))_{n\geq 0} &= (1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \dots), \\
(4^n P(n,4))_{n\geq 0} &= (1, 3, 6, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \dots), \\
(5^n P(n,5))_{n\geq 0} &= (1, 4, 12, 16, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \dots), \\
(6^n P(n,6))_{n\geq 0} &= (1, 5, 20, 44, 10, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, \dots), \\
(7^n P(n,7))_{n\geq 0} &= (1, 6, 30, 96, 90, 36, 6, 0, 0, 0, \dots), \\
(8^n P(n,8))_{n\geq 0} &= (1, 7, 42, 174, 240, 84, 28, 4, 0, 0, \dots), \\
(9^n P(n,9))_{n\geq 0} &= (1, 8, 56, 288, 690, 336, 168, 48, 6, 0, \dots), \\
(10^n P(n,10))_{n\geq 0} &= (1, 9, 72, 440, 1344, 984, 336, 144, 36, 4, 0, \dots).
\end{split}

**P.S.** I've added these values to the OEIS as the [sequence A309106](https://oeis.org/A309106).

Comment: It looks like phi(n) is involved (equal numerator?) in P(n,n+1).  Is this a classic result (P(n,n+1) equals phi(n)/((n+1)^n) )?  Can we use this to determine closed form formula for P(n,n+j) for small j?  Gerhard "Is It Even A Result?" Paseman, 2019.07.11.

Comment: Let me conjecture (n-1)(phi(n)) for P(n,n+2) and n greater than 3. Gerhard "Strike While Conjecturing Is Hot" Paseman, 2019.07.11.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: You seem to refer to $P(n-2,n)$, not $P(n,n+2)$.

Comment: Indeed, I am being sloppy. Sorry for that. In any case, something like that should hold, and can be useful. Further, it may be possible to show that phi(k) divides many of the numerators of P(n,k).  Gerhard "Did Not Edit Fast Enough" Paseman, 2019.07.11.

Comment: Actually divisibility by phi(k) seems clear to me now.  Gerhard "Watches His Excitement Level Drop" Paseman, 2019.07.11.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: Yes, it follows from the property invariant with respect to multiplying the sequence of outcomes by any residue coprime to $k$.