# Cohomology of the complement of the resonance hyperplane arrangement

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, hyperplane-arrangements

[Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/62764/a-natural-refinement-of-the-a-n-arrangement-is-to-consider-all-2n-1-hyperpl) was a question about resonance arrangement. It is defined as follows.

Let $x_i$ be the standard coordinates on $\mathbb{C}^n$. For each nonempty $I\subseteq\{1,\dots,n\}$, define the hyperplane $H_I$ to be the hyperplane given by
$l_I:=\sum _{i∈I}x_i=0$.

My question is about the top degree (co)homology of the complement
to this arrangement.

I have the following conjecture: the space of top degree forms, which are wedge products
of forms $d \log l_I$, is generated by *tree-forms*.

A tree form is defined by a rooted tree with $n$ edges labeled by $x_i$'s.
Any (non-root) vertex gives a linear function on $\mathbb{C}^n$, which is the sum of all labels on edges,
lying on the shortest path from the root to the vertex. The wedge product of $d\log$'s
of these linear functions for all vertices is the tree form.
By the way, is it a known object?

I would deeply appreciate any comments.

Comment: The resonance arrangement is notoriously difficult to understand in any nice way. One of the most recent papers about it I know of is https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.06595. (I don't think it talks about cohomology of complement of complex arrangement at all- but of course # of regions of complement of real arrangement is a closely related thing, which again is not well understood.)

Comment: For something even more recent (and in line with Sam Hopkins's comment), see https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.10553.pdf

Comment: @SamHopkins Thank you for your comment and the reference.

Comment: @user61318 Thank you for the reference.

Comment: The cohomology of hyperplane arrangements is described by the Orlik-Solomon algebra which has exactly the dlog forms as basis. Section 3 of the book of Orlik and Terao "Arrangements of hyperplanes" has a description of the "no broken circuits" basis of the top degree. I suppose that means the question is about expressing the "no broken circuits" basis in terms of your "tree form" basis.

Comment: After looking at the $n=3$ case, I believe the conjecture, but it seems to me that there are far more tree forms than necessary for generating the top-degree cohomology. My impression is that any branching leads to violation of the "no broken circuits" condition, so that the forms coming from a path of length $n$ should suffice (corresponding to the "no broken circuits" basis in Orlik-Terao).

Comment: @MatthiasWendt Dear Matthias, thank you for your interest! My impression now, that tree forms are not enough, so now I don't believe in the conjecture. But anyway I still think that this is an interesting question. If the conjecture is wrong I would be interested in looking at a counterexample.

Comment: @nikitamarkarian You're right, I forgot to include the permutations of $\{x_1+x_2,x_1+x_3,x_1+x_2+x_3\}$ in no broken circuit base for the $n=3$ case (I should've checked with the Poincaré polynomial earlier). The corresponding forms don't come from trees in an apparent way.

Comment: @MatthiasWendt Thank you very much, this is very helpful!